# Any two nonzero complex numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers

> Show that for any two nonzero complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$,
>   $$\operatorname{Log}(z_1z_2)=\operatorname{Log}(z_1)+\operatorname{Log}(z_2)+2N\pi i$$
>   $$N=0,\pm1$$
>   I know 
>   $$\operatorname{Log}(z_1z_2)=\ln(r_1r_2)+i(\theta_1+\theta_2)$$
>   that is
>   $$\operatorname{Log}(z_1z_2)=\operatorname{Log}(z_1)+\operatorname{Log}(z_2)$$
>   but where to from here?

Comment: You may want to proofread the question. $N$ is not the same as $n$ and $\log$ is not necessarily the same as $\ln$. Was the original question about $\log$ alone, or was there a capital $\operatorname{Log}$ somewhere, maybe?

Comment: Yes there was a capital Log but i couldn't find the appropriate code in the codecogs equation editor i use. the question comes from Brown and Churchill ninth edition page99 Q.1.

Comment: You can always use `\operatorname{Log}` for $\operatorname{Log}$.